# Can't import scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, scapy

I'm trying to import scapy, but it gives the below error.

```
from scapy.all import *

server_list = list()

def get_server():
    while True:


> from scapy.all import * Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "<input>", line 1, in <module>   File "C:\Program
> Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>     module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Home
> PC\PycharmProjects\testpro\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line
> 16, in <module>
>     from .arch import *   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>     module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Home
> PC\PycharmProjects\testpro\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py",
> line 95, in <module>
>     from .windows import *   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>     module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Home
> PC\PycharmProjects\testpro\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py",
> line 23, in <module>
>     from scapy.arch import pcapdnet   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>     module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Home
> PC\PycharmProjects\testpro\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py",
> line 32, in <module>
>     from .winpcapy import *   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
>     module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Home
> PC\PycharmProjects\testpro\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\winpcapy.py",
> line 26, in <module>
>     _lib=CDLL('wpcap.dll')   File "C:\Users\Home PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py",
> line 348, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I read that the backslashes are escape characters, so, we may have to use "\\" to get this imported.

I'm using Pycharm and not sure how to do this, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is that the complete error traceback? I would expect a bit more.

Comment: @Evert, there is more, added to the question. Thank you.

Comment: The last few lines indicate your problem: you're missing `wpcap.dll`. I'd search around for that: where to get it, how to install it and, if necessary, how to let `scapy` find it.

Comment: @Evert, as per your direction, my search lead me to WinPcap (looks to be a dependency for Scapy to work on Windows machines), installing it solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this when I had a scapy.py in the current directory. scapy.all import * seems to look in the current directory first.
Try to do `from scapy import all` or `import scapy.all`